# How to read cmd files

Tags: c#

I read from my starting cmd command like this:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(CmdCommandText);
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
var result=cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

But how can read another cmd files?

Comment: Um, what exactly is a 'cmd file'? A diferent exe? A different command to feed into the cmd?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. Would you please elaborate a bit more on what exactly do you need?

Comment: What do you mean "read"? Do you mean execute and capture the output? Or simply see the commands within a batch file?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you want to run a `.cmd` or `.bat` file:

Pass the `.bat` or `.cmd` filename with the `/c` or `/k` command-line options:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k \"" + pathToCmdFile + "\""
```

- `/c` will **c**lose the new console window immediately after the batch file completes.
- `/k` will **k**eep the new console window open after the batch file completes, allowing users to see any output.